# How to set spring bean properties in a .properties resource file

Tags: spring, properties, inversion-of-control, javabeans

Is this possible to set a spring bean's properties through a dot notation in a .properties file. For example suppose you have defined:

```
<bean name="myBean" class="MyBean" />
```

Is it possible to set MyBean.someProperty of myBean to a value defined in a properties file? For example by this properties file:

```
myBean.someProperty = aValue
```

I know about PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but my requirement is somewhat different from what it supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a property in your xml like that, you can assign a value from a properties file like that

```
<property name="someProperty" value="${myBean.someProperty}" />
```

which has to deal with the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

But I think, you want to override your properties, so have a look at the documentation of the [`PropertyOverrideConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer)

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. I'm curious to know if this is also possible to add map entries through PropertyOverrideConfigurer? For example you defined a bean with a map property for which a number of entries are added (in the XML file). Now you want to add more entries to the map in a property file. Is this possible?

Comment: I know, that you can do these things mit [SpringEL (Expression Language)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#d0e12535), but i am not sure, if this is also working with properties. So please have a try on your own.

Comment: Where I can put it?

Answer (score 2):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/application.properties" />

<property name="myProperty" value="${myProperty.key.of.properties}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a [`PropertyOverrideConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html) available in the Spring distribution which does exactly what you're looking for.